# How to modify when using GraphQL and Apollo

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I have a project and it is an e-commerce project and through this project I have an interface that displays all the collections on the website, and I want to edit a collection,

And the collection only has one element, which is the name of the collection, and when you click on the edit icon, a dialog appears asking to edit the name of the specified collection.

My problem is that when I press the "Save" button, the value to be modified is not modified and no action occurs.

And this is a picture of the shape of the request from backend:

[image]

This file expresses the dialog of the modification:

```
import { React, useState } from "react";
import {
  Input,
  Modal,
  ModalBody,
  ModalFooter,
  ModalHeader,
  Button,
} from "reactstrap";
import { gql, useMutation } from "@apollo/client";
import { GET_PRODUCTS } from "./dashboard";

const UPDATE_COLLECTION = gql`
  mutation updateCollection($name: String!) {
    updateCollection(updateCollection: { name: $name }) {
      name
    }
  }
`;

const EditCollection = (id, { isPublic = false }) => {
  let input;
  const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);
  const togglePopup = () => setModal(!modal);
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const handleOpen = () => setOpen(true);
  const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);
  const [collectionInput, setCollectionInput] = useState("");

  const updateCache = (cache, { data }) => {
    // If this is for the public feed, do nothing
    if (isPublic) {
      return null;
    }
    // Fetch the todos from the cache
    const existingTodos = cache.readQuery({
      query: GET_PRODUCTS,
    });
    // Add the new todo to the cache
    const newCollection = data.insert_todos.returning[0];
    cache.writeQuery({
      query: GET_PRODUCTS,
      data: { todos: [newCollection, ...existingTodos.todos] },
    });
  };

  const resetInput = () => {
    setCollectionInput("");
  };

  const [updateCollection] = useMutation(UPDATE_COLLECTION, {
    update: updateCache,
    onCompleted: resetInput,
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={togglePopup} style={{ backgroundColor: "none" }}>
        <i
          className="fa fa-pencil-square-o mr-1"
          onclick={togglePopup}
          aria-hidden="true"
        ></i>
      </Button>

      <Modal
        isOpen={modal}
        toggle={togglePopup}
        centered
        style={{ padding: "1rem" }}
      >
        <ModalHeader toggle={togglePopup} style={{ padding: "1rem" }}>
          <h3>Edit Collection</h3>
        </ModalHeader>
        <ModalBody style={{ padding: "2rem" }}>
          <Input
            // value={name}
            // onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
            // style={{ padding}}
            id="collectionName"
            name="name"
            placeholder="update collection name"
            type="text"
          />
        </ModalBody>
        <ModalFooter style={{ paddingRight: "2rem" }}>
          <Button
            color="primary"
            onclick={togglePopup}
            onSubmit={(e) => {
              e.preventDefault();
              console.log("I am inside th function: ", e.target.value);
              updateCollection({ variables: { name, id } });
              message(e);
            }}
          >
            Save
          </Button>{" "}
          <Button onclick={togglePopup}>Cancel</Button>
        </ModalFooter>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
};

export default EditCollection;
```

And through this file, I called the file for the modification

dashboard.js:

```
const AllCollections = ({ id, name, img }) => {
  return (
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">
        <Media src={img} className="blur-up lazyloaded" />
      </th>
      <td>{id}</td>
      <td>{name}</td>
      <td>
        <EditCollection id={id} />
        <i className="fa fa-trash-o ml-1" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </td>
    </tr>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining only a `name` parameter, and then giving `name` and `id`. Change your GraphQl query to supply the id as well.

```
const UPDATE_COLLECTION = gql`
  mutation updateCollection($name: String!, $id: ID!) {
    updateCollection(updateCollection: { name: $name, id:$id }) {
      name
    }
  }
`;
```

Also, to see whether the update has happened or get an error, add some console logs. And for that get them while calling `useMutation`:

```
const [updateCollection, { data, loading, error }] = useMutation(UPDATE_COLLECTION, {
    update: updateCache,
    onCompleted: resetInput,
  });
console.log(data, loading, error);
```

An finally change the save button with the code below, as you are listening to `onSubmit`, which only works on form element.

```
<Button
  color="primary"
  onClick={(e) => {
     e.preventDefault();
     console.log("I am inside th function: ", e.target.value);
     updateCollection({ variables: { name, id } });
     message(e);
     togglePopup();
  }}
 >
  Save
</Button>
```